# excel formula programming next higher second power (2^n)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to calculate the next higher second power `2^n` of a value in Excel?

For example,

I have 13 and the next higher power of two: `2^n = 2^4=^16`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Better solution:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((log(value)/log(2))+1)
```

because values like 16 also will be included!

explanation

when you miss +1 and do not rounddown, in case of a 2^n value itselve you get it selve and not the next higher one.

Comment: Better how, and than what?

Comment: because cases like 16 will be also included.

Comment: Well: 1. That requirement isn't clear in the question; 2. Nor is it mentioned in the answer that this is the difference; and 3. You have a typo.

Comment: You could probably expand on "included". It's not like the other answers don't give a result for that input, and it will depend on a given person's need whether that behaviour actually makes this "better" for them or not. And you haven't fixed the typo: *rond*down?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula:

```
=2^CEILING.MATH(LOG(A1,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If x is your value (i.e. in the example above x=13) then try the excel formula:

=ROUNDUP(LN(x)/LN(2),0)